# Multiple Nested Fields Using JQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am trying to add nested fields on the fly by using an ajax request to get the view and passing it to the form. adding new field from the ajax request works. But it wouldn't save.. I know why but I don't know the solution to this.

## THE PROBLEM

So, every time I click the add new field button. **It will not only add the new input field but it is also enclosed in a new user form tag**. I have to get rid of the form tag but retain the input select for it to be able to save the dynamically added nested fields to the database. I want to know what is the rails way to approach this problem.

### /users/ajax/new-timezone

Here's the field that is returned when an ajax GET request is called to the URL

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="JvePGr1rdBZlHEF76I8saAzQzy3nV9K8b6Xt6QpppNA="></div> <!-- I don't want this form tag -->
      <select class="form-control" id="user_timezones_attributes_1416459521_region" name="user[timezones_attributes][1416459521][region]">
      <!-- OPTION VALUES -->
      <span class="input-group-addon beautify" data-toggle="nestedfield">
        <input name="user[timezones_attributes][1416459521][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="user_timezones_attributes_1416459521__destroy" name="user[timezones_attributes][1416459521][_destroy]" type="checkbox" value="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
      </span>
</form> <!-- I don't want this form tag -->
```

## CODE

### routes.rb

```
get 'users/ajax/new-timezone' => 'users#new_field_timezone'
```

### users_controller.rb

```
# Create a new timezone field
def new_field_timezone
 @user = User.new
 @user.timezones.new
 render "new_timezone", layout: false
end
```

### _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { role: "form" } do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field(:name, class:"form-control", autofocus: true, placeholder: "Full Name") %>
      <%= render partial: "timezones_fields", locals: { f: f, child_index: Time.now.to_i } %>

      <%= f.submit 'Create account', class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

### _timezone_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :timezones, child_index: child_index do |tf| %>
    <%= tf.collection_select(:region, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all, :name, :to_s, {:include_blank => 'Please select a timezone'}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
    <span class="input-group-addon beautify" data-toggle="nestedfield">
      <%= tf.check_box :_destroy %><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### new_timezone.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <%= render partial: "timezones_fields", locals: {f: f, child_index: Time.now.to_i} %>
<% end %>
```

### dynamic_fields.js

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/users/ajax/new-timezone",
  })
  .success(function(data) {
    btn.button('reset');
    $(data)
      .hide()
      .insertBefore($('button[data-toggle="nestedfield"]'))
      .fadeIn(250);
  })
  .error(function(data) {
    console.log("There was an error inserting: " + data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this by using Ryan Bate's method of adding nested field.

### dynamic_fields.js

```
function add_field(button, association, content) {

  // Each time a new field is created the id will be unique 

  var new_id = new Date().getTime();

  // Use regular expression to find the string in the
  // id and name to be replaced example by default its
  // id="user_associations_attributes_new_association_region"
  // name="user[associations_attributes][new_association][region]"

  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");

  $(button).button('loading');
  setTimeout(function () {
        $(button).button('reset')
    }, 3000);

  $(content.replace(regexp, new_id))
        .hide()
        .insertBefore($(button))
        .fadeIn(250);

  $(button).button('reset');
}
```

### application_helper.erb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def button_to_add_field(f, association)  
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new 
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|  
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_field", :f => builder)  
    end 

    # Assign fields and association name to onclick
    # html attribute as a parameter to a javascript function
    button = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='add_field(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")' formnovalidate data-loading-text='Loading...'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button>"

    # Return a button that can be rendered
    button.html_safe
  end  
end
```

### _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { role: "form" } do |f| %>

  <!-- User form field -->
  <h3>User Form</h3>
  <%= f.text_field(:name, class:"form-control", autofocus: true, placeholder: "Full Name") %>

  <!-- Display existing nested field or new field eg: 1.times {@user.timezones.build} -->
  <h3>Nested Form</h3>
  <%= f.fields_for :association do |af| %>
    <%= af.collection_select(:something, Options.all, :name, :value, prompt: true) %>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Our helper to add more field -->
  <%= button_to_add_field f, :associations %>

<% end %>
```

### _association_field.html.erb

This will be what is used by the helper to add the field on the fly
Doesn't need the **field_for** or **form_for** method as it's just a view that receives the **f** variable from the **button_to_add_field** helper

```
<%= f.collection_select(:association_field, SomeOptions.all, :name, :value, prompt: true) %>
```